# GetCustomAttributes does not find Attribute when called through TeamBuild

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, getcustomattributes

This is way out there but maybe someone has seen this.
Maybe someone have some additional debugging ideas for `GetCustomAttributes` failures.

`Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly, Type)` returns nothing on a particular machine when called through TeamBuild.

`GetCustomAttributes` is looking for our own attribute on a dlls in a particular directory. It always finds this attribute when used in Visual Studio and usually through TeamBuild but on on particular build controller, Windows 2008 server, it fails to find the attribute.

The Attribute is defined in one dll and used in others. I cannot debug with VS on the remote machine.

I suspect there's something with duplicate assemblies being found but I haven't found anything.

I've tried Fuslogvw but nothing unusual appears, as far as I can see the assemblies are being loaded from the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Set the "msbuild platform" to x86 when build on a 64bit server:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhurig/archive/2009/11/25/building-vs2008-projects-with-tfs-build-2010.aspx

Days lost.